# Paragraph line break alignment in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm doing the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
}

  2009 &
  2010 &
  2011 &
  2012 \\

  \hline

  Menores custos &
  Menores custos &
  Liberdade de comercialização &
  Liberdade de comercialização \\

\end{tabular}
```

And getting the following:

[image]

How can I get rid of these big spaces and turn them into into 'normal' spaces, giving a better perspective of left alignment putting the words "Liberdade" and "de" together?

[image]

I need to keep these `0.2\textwidth` column widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Narrow columns are hard to handle; in these cases, one possible alternative is to use use `\raggedright` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
}

  2009 &
  2010 &
  2011 &
  2012 \\

  \hline

  Menores custos &
  Menores custos &
  Liberdade de comercialização &
  Liberdade de comercialização \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** mentions in his comment, using `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package can be a better option, since now hyphenation is allowed and it outputs less ragged columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}
}

  2009 &
  2010 &
  2011 &
  2012 \\

  \hline

  Menores custos &
  Menores custos &
  Liberdade de comercialização &
  Liberdade de comercialização \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` that allows hyphenation and outputs less ragged columns.

Comment: @egreg: yes; I've added this option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `raggedright` inside `p` columns.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
    p{0.20\textwidth}
}

  2009 &
  2010 &
  2011 &
  2012 \\

  \hline

  Menores custos &
  Menores custos &
  \raggedright Liberdade de comercialização &
  \raggedright Liberdade de comercialização 

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: beware the `\\ ` there is a forced raggedright line break, not an end of table row. As it's the end of the table anyway, safest is simply not to use `\\ `.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Uh!. Remnant of OP's code. Didn't notice at all. Thank you. Corrected now. `:-)`